# A non-commutative analog of a known result concerning a Jacobian pair

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, jacobian

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero and let $E=E(x,y) \in k[x,y]$.
Define $t_x(E)$ to be the maximum among $0$ and the $x$-degree of $E(x,0)$.
Similarly, define $t_y(E)$ to be the maximum among $0$ and the $y$-degree of $E(0,y)$.

The following nice result appears in several places, for example [1](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/39334102.pdf) [Proposition 2.1][2](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265368034_On_Appelgate-Onishi's_Lemmas) [Lemma 1.14][3](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-015-8555-2_10) [Proposition 10.2.6][4](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783764363505):
Let $A,B \in k[x,y]$ satisfy $\operatorname{Jac}(A,B) \in k-\{0\}$
(such $A,B$ is called a Jacobian pair).
Assume that the $(1,1)$-degree of $A$, $\deg(A)$, is $>1$ and the $(1,1)$-degree
of $B$, $\deg(B)$, is $>1$.
Then the numbers $t_x(A),t_y(A),t_x(B),t_y(B)$ are all positive.

> Is the same result holds in the first Weyl algebra over $k$, $A_1(k)$? where instead of the Jacobian we take the commutator.

Of course, we must first define $t_x(A),t_y(A),t_x(B),t_y(B)$ in $A_1(k)$; it seems to me that the same definition holds for $A_1(k)$, or am I missing something? Perhaps it is not possible to consider $E(x,0)$, where $E \in A_1(k)$?

Later, I have also asked this question in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334897/a-non-commutative-analog-of-a-result-concerning-a-jacobian-pair) (in MO I have slightly elaborated on a plausible proof).

Thank you very much!

Comment: I was looking at your post in MO. How is the noncommutative version of Lemma 1.3? For example, if $A=y-x^2$ and $B=x^4/2+y^2/2-x^2y$, then $[A,B]=1$, but neither $(0,1)$ nor $(1,0)$ are in $S_B$, and $(1,0)$ is not in $S_A\cup S_B$.

Comment: @san, thank you very much! Very nice! Could you please post your comment as an answer (a counterexample).

Comment: @san, so perhaps the maximum that we can say is that one of $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ belongs to $S_A \cup S_B$?

Comment: Although your map does not contradict my claim that the four $t$'s are positive (only Lemma 1.3 of Nowicki-Nakai that says that $\{(1,0),(0,1)\} \in S_A \cup S_B$), it is very interesting since it shows the difference between the commutative and non-commutative cases.

Comment: Luckily, Proposition 3.5 of the first version of https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.6100v1 shows that my claim holds, by taking an appropriate $(\rho,\sigma)$.

Comment: Well, perhaps Proposition 3.6 may not be applied here, since it is required that $\rho+\sigma \geq 0$, and I thought to take $(\rho,\sigma) = (1, -n)$ for large enough $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ($n> r$ of Theorem 5.12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non commutative version of Lemma 1.3 does not hold. In fact, set $A=y−x^2$  and $B=x^4/2+y^2/2−x^2y$, then $[A,B]=1$, but neither $(0,1)$ nor $(1,0)$ are in $S_B$, and $(1,0)$ is not in $S_A\cup S_B$. However,  if the Dixmier Conjecture is true, then every endomorphism is an automorphism, and if for an automorphism $f(x)=A$, $f(y)=B$, and $\deg(A),\deg(B)>1$, then  the numbers $t_x(A),t_y(A),t_x(B),t_y(B)$ are all positive. So a counterexample to your proposition would be a counterexample to the Dixmier Conjecture.

So your proposition is probably true, but I can't think of a way to prove it without the Dixmier Conjecture.