# Shape of possible counterexamples to the Jacobian Conjecture

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, jacobian

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero.
It is well-known that if $(x,y) \mapsto (p,q) \in k[x,y]^2$ is a counterexample to the two-dimensional Jacobian Conjecture, then there exists an automorphism $g$ of $k[x,y]$ such that the support of $g(p)$ is contained in some rectangular 
$\{ (i,j) | 0 \leq i \leq a, 0 \leq j \leq b \}$ with $(a,b)$ in the support of $g(p)$; see [Corollary 10.2.21](https://books.google.co.il/books?redir_esc=y&id=wKJqqd8t8KUC&q=proposition%2010.2.6#v=snippet&q=proposition%2010.2.6&f=false) of van den Esses's book.

> **Question 1 (easy?):** Is it true that in that case
>   we also have: $g(q)$ is contained in some rectangular $\{(i,j) | 0 \leq i \leq c, 0 \leq j \leq d\}$ with $(c,d)$ in the support of $g(q)$?

By [Proposition 2.1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.1784.pdf) (with Proposition 1.13):
$\mu x^cy^d$ is the $(1,1)$-leading term of $g(q)$, for some $\mu\ \in k-\{0\}, c,d \in \mathbb{N}$, since the $(1,1)$-leading term of $g(p)$ is $\lambda x^ay^b$, for some $\lambda \in k-\{0\}, a,b \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence, $(c,d)$ is in the support of $g(q)$.

> But should $g(q)$ be contained in some rectangular?

**Remark:** Perhaps the arguments in the proof of Corllary 10.2.21 of Essen's book
actually prove that $g(q)$ must also be subrectangular? (the argument about no edge with a negative slope).

Interestingly, in the non-commutative case, namely, in the first Weyl algebra, the answer is yes, see [Theorem 5.12](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.6100v1.pdf).

---

> **Question 2 (more difficult?):** Is it true that we can further obtain the a possible counterexample has the form: $g(p)$ is as above and, in addition, $\{(a,v)_{0 \leq v \leq b-1}\}$ are *not* in the support of $g(p)$ and
>   $\{(u,b)_{0 \leq u \leq a-1}\}$ are *not* in the support of $g(p)$?
>   Something like the picture of $(p_0,q_0)$ on [page 50](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.1784.pdf).

I think that I have once seen a half positive answer to my Question 2, see the picture on [page 21](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.6100.pdf) (there: both $P$ and $\phi(P)$ are half good for me).

---

**Edit:** My **question 1** has a positive answer thanks to [Lemma B](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265368034_On_Appelgate-Onishi's_Lemmas) or [Theorem 3.4](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002240499190128O).

Now I also asked **Question 2** in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338701/shape-of-possible-counterexamples-to-the-jacobian-and-dixmier-conjectures).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1: yes

Question 2: no

All you can say is that if $a<b$, then you can assume that (u,b) is not in the support of g(p) for $u<a$. See for example Makar-Limanov's "On the Newton polygon of a Jacobian mate" at

https://www.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/preprints

the preprint 2013-53.

I think that the picture you want to use in order to prove the positive answer to question 2, is only a particular case with (a,b)=m(4,12).

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Please note that your answer is what I have mentioned yesterday in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338701/shape-of-possible-counterexamples-to-the-jacobian-and-dixmier-conjectures. Question 2 can sometimes have a positive answer (see page 50), at least in the commutative case and when the degree is minimal.

Comment: There is no difference between the commutative and the noncommutative conjecture in this case. The picture in page 50 is a minimal counterexample under the assumption that B=16, which by corollary 7.13 yields a very specific shape for the minimal counterexample.

Comment: For example, if B=36, and the minimal counterexample has $B_0=(9,24)$ and $B_1=(9,27)$, as in remark 7.14, then a part of the right border of the rectangle is always in the support.

Comment: ok, thanks for the clarification. If we concentrate on a minimal counterexample (which is good enough for me), is it true that the picture on page 50 is also valid in the first Weyl algebra? (I guess that the answer is yes? You have written that both commutative and non-commutative cases have the same answer, so the results of that paper are also valid for $A_1$, in particular Corollary 7.13 etc.?).

Comment: As long as you consider only directions $(\rho,\sigma)$ with $\rho+\sigma> 0$ both behave the same. So Corollary 7.13 holds only for some directions. So instead of the directions in the corollary, you only can say that $Dir(P)_{\ge 0} \subset\{(-1,1),(4,-1)\}$, where $Dir(P)_{\ge 0}$ are the directions of $P$ with $\rho+\sigma\ge 0$. And once again, it is not clear at all that $B=16$, neither in the commutative nor in the non commutative case, so $B=16$ is a very strong assumption.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But under the assumption $B=16$ the same result (picture in page 50) holds in $A_1$?

Comment: No, the lower side (with direction (1,-2) may be different).

Comment: Shouldn't a direction $(\rho,\sigma)$ satisfy $\rho+\sigma \geq 0$, but in your case $\rho+\sigma = -1 \leq 0$?

Comment: That is precisely the point. In the commutative case the direction $(1,-2)$ behaves well, but in the noncommutative case it behaves badly.

Comment: But in the non commutative case, if $B=16$, then you also have a positive answer to your question 2: the support is contained strictly in the rectangle, except for the corner.

Comment: Thank you again. Please, when you say: "The support is contained strictly in the rectangle, except for the corner (corners?)", you mean that the two conditions for $g(p)$ (and then by similarity for $g(q)$ also) in my question 2 are satisfied (I guess yes) or just that $(a,0)$ and $(0,b)$ are not in the support of $g(p)$ (and $(c,0), (0,d)$ are not in the support of $g(q)$)?

Comment: Is it known that the Newton polygons of the supports of $p,q \in A_1$ such that $[p,q]=1$ are similar? In $k[x,y]$ this is well-known for a Jacobian pair (if I am not wrong, this was first proved by S. Abhyankar http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr57.pdf). This may be related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3275302/a-non-commutative-analog-of-a-known-result-concerning-a-jacobian-pair ; the commutative result is used in the proof of the similarity of the Newton polygons of a Jacobian pair.

Comment: I mean the conditions in question 2. Instead of the border with slope 1/2 you could have a border with slope 1, but with the same intersection as before (the starting point of the border with slope 1/3 doesn't change).

Comment: If you extend the support of $\ell_{1,-1}$ to the X-axis and the support of $\ell_{-1,1}$ to the Y-axis, then they are similar. So you have to kill the bad directions. Otherwise I don't think it is true. But a counterexample would be a counterexample to the Dixmier conjecture.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations.

Comment: You can see what may happen if you assume for example that $\ell_{1,-1}(P)=(x^{3}y)^2$ and $\ell_{1,-1}(Q)=(x^{3}y)^3$. Draw the support.

Comment: Thank you again. I guess you meant that I will find $P$ and $Q$ myself?

Comment: You have $\ell_{1,-1}(P)=x^6 y^2+3x^5 y$ and $\ell_{1,-1}(Q)=x^9 y^3+ 9x^8 y^2+15x^7 y$.

Comment: You can use for example Lemme 2.1 of Dixmier's "Sur les algebres de Weyl", taking into account that Dixmier's $p$ is our $x$ and his $q$ is our $y$.

Comment: But you should do some computations in $A_1$ in order to get the flavour.

Comment: ok, very nice, thank you!